# Recieving the following error: "line 36 expecting 'endmodule', found 'if'

Tags: syntax, verilog

On the line with if(lr == 0) I am recieving the following error "expecting 'endmodule', found 'if'.  The Verilog code is of a 8-bit shift register that functions as a left and right shifter and can choose between arithmetic and logical shifting.   I can't see why I am receiving the error.  It may be a some type of syntax error since I am new to Verilog.  Thanks for any help in advance.

```
module shifter(
input [7:0] shift_in,
input [2:0] shift_by,

 // 0 for left, 1 for right
input lr,

 //0 for logical, 1 for arithmetic
input arith,
output reg signed [7:0] shift_out
);

//left shift
if(lr == 0) 
begin
    assign shift_out = shift_in << shift_by;
    assign shift_out[0] = 1'b0;
end
//right shift
else begin
    //logical shift
    if (arith == 0) begin
        assign shift_out = shift_in << shift_by;
        assign shift_out[7] = 1'b0;
    //arithmetic shift
    end else begin
        assign shift_out[7] = shift_in[7];
        assign shift_out = shift_in << shift_by;
    end
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use if statments like that with assign. Place in an always block and remove the assign.

```
always @* begin
//left shift
if(lr == 1'b0) 
begin
    shift_out = shift_in << shift_by;
    shift_out[0] = 1'b0;
end
//right shift
else begin
    //logical shift
    if (arith == 0) begin
        shift_out = shift_in << shift_by;
        shift_out[7] = 1'b0;
    //arithmetic shift
    end else begin
        shift_out[7] = shift_in[7];
        shift_out = shift_in << shift_by;
    end
end
end
```